# Characterize the space of all ramification divisors of degree $d$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors, ramification

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g>0$, and let $f\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a branched covering of degree $d$. Define the ramification divisor $R_f$ on $X$ by $f$, where $\deg R_f = 2g+2d-2 :=N$. Denote $R_d = \{R_f \mid f\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^1, \deg f = d \}$.

I am interested in whether we can characterize the subset $R_d$ in the space of all effective divisors of degree $N$ on $X$, denoted as $\operatorname{Sym}^N(X)$. Specifically, is $R_d$ an algebraic subset or Zariski closed in $\operatorname{Sym}^N(X)$?

I would appreciate references on this topic, and any comments are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an elementary answer to your specific question. $R_d$ is not closed.  For instance when $X = \mathbb P^1$ and $d = 2$, a divisor $p+q$ appears as a ramification divisor if and only if $p,q$ are distinct.

To show that $2p$ cannot occur, we may WLOG assume that $p=0$ and the map takes $0$ to $0$, so in coordinates takes the form $x \mapsto\frac{ax^2 + bx}{u x^2 + vx + w}$ for $w,a \neq 0$. Thus the Taylor expansion of the map at $0$ is at most quadratic, and so the ramification multiplicity is $\leq 1$.  To show that $p +q$ can occur for any $p,q$ distinct, assume WLOG that $q = \infty$.  Then if $p = c$ the map $\frac{x^2}{2} + cx$ works.

In this case, the image is open, but this cannot happen for higher genus curves for dimension reasons.  By Chevalley's theorem, $R_d$ is at least constructible. I would also be interested to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks. The notion of a constructible set is still not quite refined for me. What I would like to inquire about is whether the inclusion of the set $R_d$ in $\operatorname{Sym}^N(X)$ can be expected to be generic.

Comment: @swalker. What do you mean by generic? If you mean dense, then the answer is no (for the same reason that it isn't open).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My generic is dense. I appreciate your clarification, and now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

For non hyper-elliptic curves and $d < g$ you can use a geometric Riemann-Roch argument:

A map $f:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d<g$ is defined by choice of a codimension $2$ linear projective subspace $A_f\subset|K_C|^*$, where the $d=g-\#A_f\cap C$, the fibers of $f$ are the intersections $H\cap C$ for hyperplanes $H\supset A_f$, and the ramification points are the ones where these fibers acquire multiplicities.

We can dualize this as follows: Let $l_f:=A_f^\perp$ in $|K_C|$, and let $C^\vee\subset|K_C|$ be the dual hypersurface. Let $D$ be the smooth part of $C^\vee$, and let $\pi:D\to C$ be the map taking a tangent to a point ot that point. Then $R_f \subset \pi(l_f\cap D)-A_f\cap C$, and if the ramfication locus does not hit a point which pulls back to a point of $C^\vee\smallsetminus D$, there is an equality.

I don't know if this is considered explicit enough, I only covered small degrees, and I still have the problem with $D$ vs $C^\perp$.